# How can I update column with type TIMESTAMP in Oracle via sql query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, timestamp

I have column:

```
"LASTTOUCH" TIMESTAMP(9) NOT NULL ENABLE
```

and I must set current date to this column.

But I have no idea how I can do it.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Insert:

```
insert into tablename (LASTTOUCH) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Update:

```
update tablename set LASTTOUCH=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the current time (including the timestamp precision), you could use either systimestamp or current_timestamp

```
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-OCT-12 11.39.37.670428 AM -04:00

SQL> select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-OCT-12 11.39.51.021937 AM -04:00

update table_name set column_name = SYSTIMESTAMP where id = 100;
```

If you just set the value to sysdate, the fractional seconds part of the timestamp is zeroed out as the date is implicitly converted to timestamp.

```
SQL> create table t1(
  2     time1 timestamp
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

SQL> select to_char(time1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF6') result from t1;

RESULT
-----------------------------
10/04/2012 11:43:07.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (SYSDATE);
```

OR

```
UPDATE tableName SET COLUMN = SYSDATE;
```